# Flutter Bloc: state not rebuilding

Tags: flutter, firebase, stream, state, bloc

I have a bloc listening to chats. Through the debugger, I can see that the bloc is catching live updates. However, the ui is not rebuilding when these changes occur. To see a change, I have to leave and reload the screen.

My chat state:

```
part of 'chat_bloc.dart';

abstract class ChatState extends Equatable {
  const ChatState();

  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [];
}

class ChatLoading extends ChatState {}

class ChatLoaded extends ChatState {
  final List<Chat?>? compiledChats;

  const ChatLoaded({required this.compiledChats});

  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [compiledChats];
}
```

My chat events:

```
part of 'chat_bloc.dart';

abstract class ChatEvent extends Equatable {
  const ChatEvent();

  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [];
}

class LoadChat extends ChatEvent {
  const LoadChat();

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [];
}

class CloseChat extends ChatEvent {
  const CloseChat();

  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [];
}

class UpdateChat extends ChatEvent {
  final List<List<Chat?>> chats;

  const UpdateChat({required this.chats});

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [chats];
}
```

My actual bloc:

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:bloc/bloc.dart';
import 'package:equatable/equatable.dart';
import 'package:hero/blocs/auth/auth_bloc.dart';
import 'package:hero/models/chat_model.dart';
import 'package:hero/models/user_model.dart';
import 'package:hero/repository/firestore_repository.dart';

part 'chat_event.dart';
part 'chat_state.dart';

class ChatBloc extends Bloc<ChatEvent, ChatState> {
  final FirestoreRepository _firestoreRepository;
  late StreamSubscription _chatListener;

  ChatBloc({
    required FirestoreRepository firestoreRepository,
  })  : _firestoreRepository = firestoreRepository,
        super(ChatLoading()) {
    on<LoadChat>(_onLoadChat);
    on<UpdateChat>(_onUpdateChat);
    on<CloseChat>(_onCloseChat);
  }

  void _onLoadChat(
    LoadChat event,
    Emitter<ChatState> emit,
  ) {
    _chatListener = _firestoreRepository.chats.listen((chats) {
      add(
        UpdateChat(
          chats: chats,
        ),
      );
    });
  }

  void _onUpdateChat(
    UpdateChat event,
    Emitter<ChatState> emit,
  ) {
    //generate compiledChats from event.chats
    List<Chat?>? compiledChats = [];
    for (List<Chat?> chatList in event.chats) {
      for (Chat? chat in chatList) {
        if (chat != null) {
          compiledChats.add(chat);
        }
      }
    }
    emit(ChatLoaded(compiledChats: compiledChats));
  }

  void _onCloseChat(
    CloseChat event,
    Emitter<ChatState> emit,
  ) {
    _chatListener.cancel();

    print('ChatBloc disposed');

    emit(ChatLoading());
  }

  @override
  Future<void> close() async {
    super.close();
  }
}
```

For the scope of this problem, all that really matters is just looking at the updateChat and LoadChat methods. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Add how you load bloc state into your widget.

Comment: you should add bloc builder if want to change the view.